# Problem with cifs-util. Mount: only root can mount

Tags: mount, permissions, samba, fstab, cifs

i'm trying to use `cifs-utils` to get files in another machine. In the other machine i've installed samba. Everything works fine if a try in the same machine (the one with samba) using cifs-util, but it doesn't if i try with another in the intranet. Here's what i've done:

1. i've installed cifs-util
2. i've added the following line to the `/etc/fstab` file:

   ```
   //192.168.0.72/Triple_RDF /media/Triple cifs credentials=/home/ubuntu/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
   ```
3. i've created the `.smbcredentials` file typing:

   ```
   gedit ~/.smbcredentials
   ```

   and adding the lines

   ```
   username=[username]
   password=[password]
   ```

   Of course i put my real username and password instead of [username] and [password].
4. then i changed the permits of the previous file typing:

   ```
   chmod 600 ~/.smbcredentials
   ```

Since i'm using Ubuntu 14.04 it apppears an icon on the nautilius bar (the one on the left side), but when i click on it appens nothing. If i try to go inside of the "Triple" which now appears with my network resources the system says:

```
mount: only root can mount //192.168.0.72/Triple_RDF on /media/Triple.
```

I thought that may be it could be a problem of permits in the destination folder, `/media/Triple`. So i changed those. Here my `ls -al` output of the `/media/Triple` folder:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 user group 4096
```

where instead of user and group i put the real ones.

Anybody knows which could be the problem ?

Answer: make sure you have installed cifs-utils and you have user in the fstab entry.

Comment: According to OP's answer I am voting to close this as "not reproducible".

Answer (score 12):

Just add users in `/etc/fstab` like that:

```
//192.168.0.72/Triple_RDF /media/Triple cifs credentials=/home/ubuntu/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,users 0 0
```

Normally, only the superuser can mount filesystems. However, when fstab contains the **user** option on a line, anybody can mount the corresponding system.

Or if you want any user to mount/unmount the drives use **users** instead.

Comment: Why and what does it do, what you suggest here? Can you please elaborate? Thx

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same problem by adding the UID info as an admin user from my Linux machine, so my `/etc/fstab` line now looks like this:

```
//192.168.1.X/Multimedia /media/dungeonmultimedia cifs uid=[linuxadminuser],username=[nasadminuser],password=[nasadminpass] 0 0
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please review my edits and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... ;-)

Comment: You're welcome!  1 upvote = +10 rep!  **;-)**

Comment: This worked for me when nothing else would. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem was that I hadn't restarted the system, so I had mounted nothing.

Restarting the system or just forcing the mount everything works perfectly.
I've just typed:

```
sudo mount -a
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I put it in `/etc/fstab` so it mounts automatically on boot.

Comment: I recommend expanding this answer (through editing) to explain how to do this, perhaps with an example `fstab` line based on what you use.