# Nautilus doesn't display the content of a network share, but I can access it via terminal

Tags: networking, mount, nautilus, samba, fstab

This problem puzzles me: I can't access the files of a windows network share via nautilus, but I can open the folder and manipulate the files fine via the terminal.

Here is the entry in my `/etc/fstab`

```
//ip/share_name  /media/georg/mount_point  cifs users,uid=georg,credentials=/home/georg/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

The mount point shows up in nautilus, but clicking simply does nothing, not even hang it.

I have been playing around with the fstab settings a bit, tried different security settings, but I can't find a configuration that works. The settings above were taken from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently.

I am using Ubuntu 16.10. The network share is mounted on a Windows server, that I have used before on a different install (not without problems, but those were concerning connection speed, I could always mount it).

Any help is appreciated.

#### edit

So I am still suffering from this, and I again started to play around with it. I still have hope that some day somebody stumbles over this question :). Without the 'users' flag, I can reproduce the error in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493523/problem-with-cifs-util-mount-only-root-can-mount) ('only root can mount' error upon click)

Comment: Silly question(s), you probably already did,  but is the drive in the output of `lsblk`, and what happens if you run `sudo mount -a`?

Comment: yes, I did `sudo mount -a` without any different result. Haven't checked if the drive is in `lsblk`, thats for the suggestion. It isn't though.